# Find meeting point and position content crossing over, javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to find out where 2 divs meet each other and position content crossing over both divs. I will never know how big my divs are since the number varies depending on scenario.

The first img shows what I need, the second one shows my problem when there are only 2 columns instead.

So I'm looking for a way with javascript to find out how wide my columns are, find the point where the divs meet, and position the content centered over the crossing. I hope you understand what I mean.

I tried doing it with css, but with little success.
So there is no js in this at all yet. Any vanilla or jquery solution would be great.

What I need:

[image: Image showing what I need]

What I have:

[image: Image showing my problem]

```css
#wrapper {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#wrapper div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.overlap {
  background: #010101;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  min-width: 100px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  right: -50%;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>
    <p>one
      <span class="overlap">phase</span>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
  <div>four</div>
</div>
```

Comment: your code example doesn't show your `overlap` class nor does it contain any javascript.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added the overlap class. And wrote a little better explanation. I tried to google a solution to find out where two divs meet each other using js but I found nothing matching my needs. So there is no js in there yet.

Comment: You could position the overlap INSIDE the first column in your html, then make the first column `position: relative` and finally position the overlap to the right of it with `position: absolute; transform: translateX(50%); right: 0;`. This would work but as I said, the `.overlap` has to be inside the first column.

Comment: That works, thank you!